# Kubernetes ingress communication with nginx inside pod (serving SPA)

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have single page application. It was developed for using with HTTP2 (no bundles and other HTTP1.1 optimization). But now I need to move it to `kubernetes`. If I understand correctly, I can use `ingress controller` with `TLS termination` and `HTTP2`, but how will `ingress` communicate with `pod`? Will it use `HTTP1.1`?

I tried to deploy this application, and saw a decrease in response performance on every downloaded file. The biggest decrease was when downloading the first files.

What is the best way to serve static files from a webserver (`nginx`) inside a `pod` through `ingress` with `HTTP2`?

Comment: There is always an overhead of encryption. Think about what is going on where with each request. client and server do protocol handshake, server encrypt content and send back to client. now client has to decrypt it before presenting back to caller.

Comment: I had http2 (with encryption) without kubernetes. Now ingres with http2 (with encryption) and simple pod with nginx serving spa. So ingress to nginx pod works through http(without encryption)

Comment: I think ingress is a simple client to nginx in the pod. When it communicate with http1.1 all optimization of the application for http2, on the contrary, leads to a loss of performance